# 'Function to return a choices array' in NPM inquirer (JavaScript)

Tags: javascript, mysql, mysql2, inquirer, inquirerjs

I am trying to figure out how to use a function to return choices in an inquirer prompt but I can't seem to find any examples or explanations on how to do this. I have a MySQL2 query:

```
db.query(`SELECT id AS value, name FROM departments`, (req, res) => {
    return Object.values(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(res)))
})
```

returning an array of objects:

```
[
  { value: 1, name: 'Sales' },
  { value: 2, name: 'Engineering' },
  { value: 3, name: 'Finance' },
  { value: 4, name: 'Legal' },
  { value: 5, name: 'Human Resources' }
]
```

which seems like the returned array would fulfill what I need in my prompt:

```
{
        type: 'list',
        name: 'department',
        message: 'In which department is this role?',
        choices: [// CODE HERE]
}
```

but I keep getting 'undefined'.
I have tried to put the MySQL query straight into the choices array.
I have tried `return` as well as `console.log` and `map`.
I have tried putting the query in a function and then calling the function within the choices prompt.

I have also confirmed that hardcoding my array of objects into the choices prompt does print successfully, but I don't want to hard code as other questions in the prompt allow the client to add to the departments table and I want that to be reflected in the choices.

What am I missing?

Comment: `choices` used to accept a function. Instead of using `[]`, declare a function there.

Answer (score 0):

consider that when using async operation in choices function, you must return a promise

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).